# How to define a RegularExpresion Validation for an Controller Action Param, in TYPO3 v10/v11?

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x, typo3-11.x

I'm updating an extension for usage in TYPO3 v10 or higher and have an issue with a regular Expression validator, i don't know how to get in runnable in v10 or higher now. Tried the following:

```
/**
 * action list
 *
 * @param string $filterChar
 * @Extbase\Validate("RegularExpression",options={ "regularExpression": "/^[0-9A-Za-z]{0,1}$/i" })
 * @return void
 */
public function listAction(string $filterChar = '') {
```

But i got the following exception:

```
Invalid validate annotation in ABC\MyExt\Controller\MyController->listAction(): The following validators have been defined for missing param "$": RegularExpression
```

What i'm doing wrong and how can i fix it, or what is the correct definition now for a RegularExpression validator for an action parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. I had to add the param="..."

```
@Extbase\Validate("RegularExpression",options={ "regularExpression": "/^[0-9A-Za-z]{0,1}$/i" }, param="filterChar")
```

So the full solution looks like this:

```
/**
 * action list
 *
 * @param string $filterChar
 * @Extbase\Validate("RegularExpression",options={ "regularExpression":"/^[0-9A-Za-z]{0,1}$/i" }, param="filterChar")
 * @return void
 */
public function listAction(string $filterChar = '') {
```